# ReplaceAll problem

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 11.0.1**

Confirmed, as bug, by WRI: [CASE:3402234]

---

I am trying to combine terms of the type `term+Transpose[term]`. I have done the following:

```
ReplaceAll[a.b.c.d + a.ss.e.g.r + Transpose[a.b.c.d], {
  Plus[front___, term__, middle___, Transpose[term__], end___] :> 
   Plus[front, middle, end, 2*term]
  }]
```

However this gives back:

```
Out= a.b.c.d + a.ss.e.g.r + Transpose[a.b.c.d]
```

How come I am not getting back `2 a.b.c.d+a.ss.e.g.r`? Thanks!

Comment: I get `2 a.b.c.d+a.ss.e.g.r`

Comment: Whaaaaat? I have Mathematica 10.2...

Comment: @space_voyager You might try wrapping Trace around your expression, carefully read the details of the help page for Trace and then study the output from your expression. That can sometimes help you find why a pattern isn't matching. With that I found that a pattern of term_+Transpose[term_]:>2*term seems like it might be sufficient and might avoid some of the matching problems. See what you can make of this.

Comment: Mma v9 here ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SwvND.png)

Comment: Why do you do this to me, Wolfram??

Comment: I think this is a bug and should be reported to WRI, but let's wait with bugs tag until someone else also thinks this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem on Mma 10.1 on OS X 10.10.4 I took off one of the blanks on *term*, i.e.

```
ReplaceAll[a.b.c.d + a.ss.e.g.r + Transpose[a.b.c.d],
 {Plus[front___, term__, middle___, Transpose[term__], end___] :>
   Plus[front, middle, end, 2*term]}]
```

> a.b.c.d + a.ss.e.g.r + Transpose[a.b.c.d]

```
ReplaceAll[a.b.c.d + a.ss.e.g.r + Transpose[a.b.c.d],
 {Plus[front___, term_, middle___, Transpose[term_], end___] :>
   Plus[front, middle, end, 2*term]}]
```

> 2 a.b.c.d + a.ss.e.g.r

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution that worked for me :)

Answer (score 9):

I think you've found a bug in pattern matcher.

This problem can be reduced to matching sequence of length one with named `BlankSequence` patterns in `Orderless` functions, it stopped working in v10.1. In previous versions your replacement rule works (as [noted by belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91433/14303#comment-248293)).

Minimal example of this behavior is:

```
ClearAll[f, a]
SetAttributes[f, {Orderless}]

$Version
MatchQ[{f[a], a}, {f[x__], x__}]
```

In different versions I get:

> "8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 7, 2010)"
>
> True

---

> "9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 7, 2013)"
>
> True

---

> "10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"
>
> True

---

> "10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"
>
> False

---

> "10.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 6, 2015)"
>
> False

If we use `Blank` instead of `BlankSequence`, remove name from one of patterns or use non-`Orderless` function, then pattern matches in all versions:

```
ClearAll[g]
MatchQ[{f[a], a}, {f[x_], x_}]
MatchQ[{f[a], a}, {f[x__], __}]
MatchQ[{g[a], a}, {g[x__], x__}]
(* True
   True
   True *)
```

---

As to your original replacement, as [noted by Bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91433/14303#comment-248292) due to `Flat`, `OneIdentity` and `Orderless` attributes of `Plus` you can use:

```
a.b.c.d + a.ss.e.g.r + Transpose[a.b.c.d] /. term_ + Transpose[term_] :> 2*term
(* 2 a.b.c.d + a.ss.e.g.r *)
```